# Is there a node that can reverse the masking area in Compositing?

Tags: compositing-nodes

Is there a node that can reverse the masking area in Compositing?
I want the mesh to appear outside of the area, but I don't know how to mask it.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Masks are just greyscale images so Invert node inverts the masking:

[image]